# Is there a macro or provision to check is the line of code is inside a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I have a c style macro in my code, which prints the logs. I want to alter the macro to print the *this* pointer. But, there are some portion of a code, which is not a member function of a class or some are static functions. So, in my macro I want to check, the current line of code is inside a member function or not. Possible?

Comment: Have you tried `__FUNCTION__` macro already? I know it shows the name of the function you're located in, but I don't know in case of a class method whether or not the class name is shown.

Comment: @Dominique: That's not a macro, see my answer why it can't be. As such it's unavailable to the preprocessor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The preprocessor, as the name says, runs first. Interpreting a sequence of tokens as a class definition is done by the compiler, which runs *after* the preprocessor. Therefore the preprocessor has no idea about classes, or functions, or variables, or any other C++ construct.

BTW, inside a class you still have `static` methods that don't have `this` pointers either.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this doesn't exactly fit your demands but it may be doable to integrate that in a build environment. (Edit: I just realize that it fails for static member functions; hm.)

My idea is to define a function `log()`  twice: one is in the global namespace; it is the obvious result of name resolution for calls from within freestandig functions. The other `log()`  is a member function of a base class from which all classes which want to log must inherit. (That's the bad thing; for a big existing code base that's hardly doable.) The inheritance, function definitions and calls can be made dependent on a preprocessor define so that they have no influence on production code:

```
#include<cstdio>
// The following would go in a header which must be included by all source
// files which use one of the macros, i.e. which want to log errors.
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define INHERIT_LOG() : virtual protected logT
#   define LOG(s) log(s)
    /** ::log which will be called by free-standing functions */
    static void log(const char *err, const void *thisP = nullptr) 
    { 
        if(thisP) { fprintf(stderr, "this=%p: %s\n", thisP, err); }
        else      { fprintf(stderr, "free func: %s\n", err); }
    }

    /** A base class to inherit from when logging is required */
    class logT
    {   // this name "log" will be preferred over ::log 
        // from within all classes which inherit from logT.
        protected: void log(const char *const err){ ::log(err, this); }
    };
#else
//  define the macros to do nothing
#   define INHERIT_LOG()
#   define LOG(s)
#endif
////////////// end of log header ///////////////

/** Inherits from logT only when DEBUG is defined */                          
struct T INHERIT_LOG() { void f(); };

void T::f() { LOG("message from T::f"); }// if LOG is expanded to log, calls logT::log
void f()    { LOG("message from ::f"); } // if LOG is expanded to log, calls     ::log 

int main()
{
    T().f();
    f();
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -o log log.cpp && ./log
$ g++ -DDEBUG -std=c++14 -Wall -o log log.cpp && ./log
this=0xffffcc00: message from T::f
free func: message from ::f
$
```

Comment: This looks fragile in the presence of multiple inheritance and/or templates.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I wouldn't be sure which this pointer is printed. One could use the LOG define to obtain the this pointer *in situ*

Comment: That's not the problem (it will be the `this` pointer of the `logT` subobject), the problem is that the lookup of `log` is ambiguous in the presence of multiple `logT` subobjects. I.e. you can have `base1::logT::log` and `base2::logT::log`.

Comment: @MSalters That this pointer may not be what the OP wants to see ;-).. Regarding multiple inheritance: shouldn't the `virtual`  take care of that?

Comment: On closer inspection, it looks OK. `logT` has a default ctor, so no initialization problems.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not easily possible. There are no ways to check if a variable is defined or not in the preprocessor.

You can introduce a new logic (like inserting something into each
function which defines it type), but it is probably much easier
to have two of your macros for the case if `this` is defined or not.